# Is it possible to deploy one django application on to multiple servers using jenkins or any other tool?

Tags: jenkins, django-deployment

I am using jenkins for continuous deployment ,is it possible to deploy the single on to multiple servers ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can either use scripts or plugins in Jenkins to do this, or use something like octopus deploy to deploy the application. What works best for you depends on the the requirements for the application and servers you have.

Comment: If you have any link as reference ,please share !

Comment: [With jenkins pipeline.](https://medium.com/@evasilchenko/continuous-deployment-of-django-applications-part-1-e3bc332bcbaf)

[Octupus deploy with python application.](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/octopus-deploy-python-bruce-van-horn?articleId=6980875186061122022)

If you want more specific, it is a lot of easily searchable guides on google.